# Bounds on eigenvalues for product of non-square orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, upper-lower-bounds

Given two real matrices ${\bf A}$ and ${\bf B}$ of shape $m \times n$ with $m > n$. Let the columns within each of the matrices ${\bf a}_j$ and ${\bf b}_j$ be orthogonal and of unit norm. Such that
$$
{\bf A}^T{\bf A} = {\bf I}\quad\text{and}\quad {\bf A}{\bf A}^T \neq {\bf I}\text{,}
$$
$$
{\bf B}^T{\bf B} = {\bf I}\quad\text{and}\quad {\bf B}{\bf B}^T \neq {\bf I}\text{.}
$$
Then, define the $n \times n$ matrix ${\bf C} = {\bf A}^T{\bf B}$ with respective eigenvalues $\lambda_i$.

Is there a respective upper and lower bound on the absolute value of the largest $|\lambda_\text{max}|$ and smallest $|\lambda_\text{min}|$ eigenvalue? And more importantly, when are these bounds achieved?

I have the hypotheses that $|\lambda_\text{max}|$ should be smaller $1$ as long as ${\bf A} \neq {\bf B}$ and equal to $1$ if ${\bf A} = {\bf B}$; and that $|\lambda_\text{min}|$ should be larger $0$ as long as none of the columns are reversed, i.e., no ${\bf a}_j = - {\bf b}_j$, but don't know how to show it.

Comment: the upper bounds of 0 and 1 hold but neither bound is strict, even when $A\neq B$.  I'd suggest playing around with $4\times 4$ matrices to come up with counter examples to your conjecture on strictness.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $BA^t$ with $D$. We have $\lambda(A^tB)/0=\lambda(BA^t)/0.$ And $\lambda(D^tD)/0=\lambda(AB^tBA^t)/0=\lambda(AA^t)/0=\lambda(A^tA)/0=1.$ Consider the definition of spectral norm, then $\vert\lambda(C)\vert_\max=\vert\lambda(D)\vert_\max\leq 1.$